# Any way to correctly merge two time series with different dims in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I intend to join two time series with different dimensions in pandas. first time series is about covid19 daily case data, while second time series is daily cut statistics of food processing plants, then I want to join merged dataframe with another data by its common column. First of, I want to join them by date with certain specification. in covid case time series, data is recorded based on county level, while in daily cut time series, there is daily cut statistics which can be either average daily cut time series for each county or it is uniformly distributed. To make joining these two time series more logical, I did some aggregation and tried to join but it is not working as I expected. Can anyone suggest possible way of making this happen in pandas? Any idea?

**current attempt & reproducible data**

Here is [covid time series data in gist](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/37b0711852518cd6db4d35d4a6691a2d) came from NYT covid19 data and [daily cut time series](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/0f5f614d6b8ee3094754cd0a9d83b266) from food processing agency. Here is my current attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.read_csv("us_covid_by_counties.csv")
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True) 

df2= pd.read_csv("daily_cut.csv")
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

## process and aggregate covid time series
ctyList = list(df1['county'].unique())
df1_new= {}
for c in ctyList:
    cty_df = df1[df1['county']==c]
    cty_df['new_cases'] = cty_df['cases'].diff()
    cty_df['new_deaths'] = cty_df['deaths'].diff()
    df1_new[c] = cty_df

df1_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df1_new, orient='index')
```

then, I tried to merge them in this way:

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df1_new , df2]).sort_values('date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**update**:

if merging `df1_new` and `df2` can be done correctly, I want to join again `df_merged` with [this data](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/8d7610af305853f13ebed9ab06c380fb) by `county_state`. Is there any way to get this right in pandas?

but I have hard time to correctly join these two time series. Can anyone suggest any possible idea to make this work? Any possible thoughts?

Comment: Please check pandas `pandas.merge_asof` merge option. Something like this `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="time_column", direction='nearest')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original question you mentioned two dataframes. In your comment you mentioned another dataframe. Is this a different question? The `merge_asof` works for your original dataset. Please see below

[image: This is the second dataframe]

[image]

This is to change the datatype to datetime

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

Here is the output i got

[image]

Comment: thanks. just out of curiosity, what is the best way to join output of your above attempt with [this data](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/8d7610af305853f13ebed9ab06c380fb)? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: did you try `df1.merge(df2, on = 'county_state', how='inner')` where df1 is your first data set that is already merged using time and df2 is the new dataset you showed in the link above.

Comment: right, I tried but I think joining output is not right to me. I also tried right join. Maybe you can bring up right way to do this. Could you show how it can be done correctly for merged dataframe with [this data](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/8d7610af305853f13ebed9ab06c380fb)? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

To complete @XXavier 's suggestion in the comments:

Make sure you import dates correctly:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data/us_covid_by_counties.csv', parse_dates=['date']).drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('data/daily_cut.csv', parse_dates=['date']).drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
```

Add the columns you want:

```
df1['new_cases'] = df1.groupby(['county'])['cases'].diff()
df1['new_deaths'] = df1.groupby(['county'])['deaths'].diff()
```

Create the merged df:

```
df_merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="date", direction='nearest')
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to join `df_merged` with [this data](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/8d7610af305853f13ebed9ab06c380fb), using `pd.merge_asof()` is not working. What should I do? Any idea? Thanks :)